# Sending SSH command without waiting for it to load?

Tags: php, ssh, command, putty

I was wondering if there is a way of making a php page send an SSH command and disconnect immediately? Like screen it so it carries on after its disconnected?

Is this possible? My friend has done it but wont tell me how... he said Sockets..?

Answer (score 0):

You could use screen, but I would suggest nohup. Provided you that you are using a public/private key login instead of password, and no safe_mode restrictions, then you could do the following:

```
<?php exec("ssh <User>@<Host> 'nohup ls > test.txt &'"); ?>
```

Alternatively use the [PHP ssh2](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ssh2.php) module

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'nohup ls > test.txt &');
?>
```

nohup and the & character will still disconnect you immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting freeduck's answer to use [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/)...

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('nohup lus > test.txt &');
?>
```